# sample selectin.Statistics

Tags: statistics

The journal lists the 1900 most active kuala lumpur Stock Exchange stock exchange issues. How many samples of three are possible when selected from these 1900 stock?

the answer is 1 141 362 300, but I can' get that exact answer. Any guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is $$\binom{1900}{3}=1141362300$$ which is a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  It's the number of ways of choosing a subset of $3$ objects from a set of $1900$ distinguishable objects.

Comment: yeah, but how did you come up with this?

Comment: Largely from familiarity with the binomial coefficient: $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of subsets of size $k$ from a set of size $n$.  It can be derived combinatorially: the number of sequences of length $k$ with distinct elements is $n \times (n-1) \times \cdots (n-k+1)$, but these are ordered, so each subset of size $k$ is counted $k!$ times.  So $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{k!}n \times (n-1) \times \cdots (n-k+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\ k!}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just now I solved it...